# Reduce power use on computer

Tags: windows-7, power-supply, power-management, power-consumption

I watch a lot of movie's on my computer which is connected to my TV. Problem is i built the pc to be a gaming computer and it has the power supply to match (1200w).

Is there a way to set it into a "Low power mode" whilst i am playing a movie to use as little power as possible.

I am running - 
Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
VLC for playing movies
Connect to my TV via a standard HDMI cable

Comment: Modern CPUs should not use any more power than necessary, and they usually have the ability to change the clock speed dynamically. Look for a BIOS setting called Cool and Quiet (AMD) or EIST or SpeedStep (Intel). I don't use Windows 7, so I don't know if there are any specific settings required there, but check the Power Options in the control panel.

Comment: @user55325, you should have made this comment an answer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/106792/does-a-power-supply-draw-only-as-much-power-as-it-needs) is correct, then you may not be using as much power as you thought when playing movies. If you want to verify that for yourself, you could always borrow or buy a Kill-a-Watt or similar inline power meter and see how much the PC draws during different activities.

Comment: Thanks man i will check this out, im sure i have one laying about somehwere

Answer (score 4):

Easiest thing I can suggest is that if you turn your machine off when not using it, purchase a 1080p HDMI movie player - you can get them from as low as £20, but the good ones (with ethernet ports) start from about £45.

There isn't that much you can do on your computer to significantly lower power (apart from turn off the screen, underclock the CPU)... and as you have a 1200w PSU, I am guessing it is a beefy machine - even idling, those cards will (probably) be taking an awful lot of power....

...If you were to buy the media player and turn off your computer, it will probably pay for itself in no time.